# Run function after CSS transition completes

Tags: css, css-transitions

If I have a series of CSS background-color fade transitions running, and it's not clear when the final transition will end, how can I run a javascript function, or perform an action, as soon as a specified CSS transition ends without relying on setting a timer?

Comment: Do you know what the final transition is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the transitionend event:

```
element.addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rx8cm9Lh/

Some older browsers may require vendor prefixes. Docs are at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Comment: Im going with the jQuery `$("#currentBlock").bind`... I added ID `currentBlock` to the block running the transition... so I can pass that into the bind... and try to console.log("end") to the bound element... but it's not outputting anything

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle out of this?